# Junit testing, testing contructor, testing static array in abstract class

Tags: java, arrays, junit, polymorphism, abstract-class

I have this simple code below. I want to test the constructor to see if my board array has the correct number of rows and columns as passed in and whether each cell is "empty" or not. How do I do this?

```
public abstract class Game {

    protected BoardCell[][] board; 

    /**
     * Defines a board with BoardCell.EMPTY cells.
     * 
     * @param maxRows
     * @param maxCols
     */
    public Game(int maxRows, int maxCols) {
        /*
         * Initialize the static board two-dimensional array with rows and columns
         * equal to that passed in through the parameters.
         */
        this.board = new BoardCell [maxRows][maxCols];

        //Clears each cell in the array.
        for(int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < maxCols; j++){
                board [maxRows][maxCols] = BoardCell.EMPTY;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Create a proper instance of `Game`, then assert the expected results on that instance using the methods you have. I don't see any static or other problem here.

Comment: you can't create an instance for an abstract class though.

Comment: Again, create **A PROPER INSTACE** of your class. If you still don't have any **PROPER** subclasses, then create an anonymous class if that's what you want/need, but you will be testing this anonymous class and not the abstract class. In fact, testing is for specific classes, not for abstract classes/interfaces.